digitalassetlinks failed with deadline_exceeded
I'm trying to set up applinks on my react native android app.
I used android studio App Links Assistant to generate Digital Asset Links file with release and debug Signing config (both give the same sha256). I did save the file to my website and test it success with postman (return application/json) and success with web browser.
But the verify failed when using Android Studio

It also failed when testing with https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://my_host&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

When use adb to test on emulator, a disambiguation dialog always show up. I tried everything on Internet but don't find solution why it not work. Any suggestion?
Here is my activity AndroidManifest.xml
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            
            <data android:host="my_host" android:pathPrefix="/my_prefix"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/errors/core_errors

@gtxtreme sorry but i can find the deadline_exceeded error in the link you comment, can you be more specific? thanks
